# Xcode4 and the darn SCM

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4

I have

- project A (old),
- project B (new), and
- project C (new).

I want to use a few classes from project A in the new projects B and C.

- Project A **is** under source
  control (Subversion).
- Project B **is** under
  source control (Subversion).
- Project C
  **is not** under source control.

When i copy files from project A to project B and project C, the subversion reference doesn't change. Meaning, changes to the files are reflected in project A as well. Also, i don't want the files copied into project C to be tied with project A's subversion repository. How can i do that? I don't see any way to get rid of that damn svn status from Project A's files (in Project B or C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by deleting the .svn folders. Maybe this'll help someone else who stumble across this post.

http://www.hacktrix.com/how-to-delete-svn-folders-from-your-project-on-windows-linux-and-mac

p.s. Subversion integration with Xcode4 is bad. At it's core, Xcode3 used to work great with Subversion. The feature that i miss the most is the export (a copy of your source that's not tied with the source-control e.g. subversion).

Comment: That (exporting) somewhat defeats the purpose of SCM. Why even bother with SCM at that point?

Comment: Well, if that was the case, i'm sure the developers of Subversion wouldn't have added the `export` command. In some situation you may feel the need to grab a separate copy, which is not under source-control, to play around with it and then scrap it... or send that copy to someone else (if it's, for example, a test project).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this with Xcode's current SCM integration is not to fight it (by mixing project members). Instead, consider placing your disparate projects together within the same workspace. Read up on Xcode's new Workspace feature - projects share the same build folder and interdependencies are (usually) automatically recognized between projects.

Comment: Maybe copying files instead of referring to the same file from with-in multiple projects is not the way to go, and fighting the SCM integration across multiple projects is also not the right way, BUT i have to, because that's the kind of situation i'm in. Thanks for the advise though.

Comment: "because that's the kind of situation I'm in" - I'm not sure I understand you. If you explain that in more detail, SO might be abe to help...